# Can't find Resonance Occlusion Plugin on UE4 Platform Tab

Tags: resonance-audio

As the name says I'm incapable of finding this option when I try to set up my project on Unreal. The only option available is "Built-in Occlusion". I'm working with the new audio engine.
Thanks

[link to screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHagW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Occlusion plugin was added on a newer version than the one in Epic's release branch.

I am guessing you are using version 1.0.0 of the plugin.

If you will clone the repository from [here](https://github.com/resonance-audio-unreal/UnrealEngine)
you'll see that the plugin version is 1.2.2 and it contains the Occlusion plugin.

Unfortunately it is not updating with Epic's updates so you'll have to use 4.19.0
Or try to implement the newer plugin yourself on Epic's release branch.

Good luck.